# Dynamic label caption in a report using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to design an indididual report card for the students of my college. I have a table called "tbl_student" where their marks are stored. I have 6 columns for 6 different subjects. A student can choose only 5 subjects i.e 4 being required and Computer and Maths are optional subjects where a student can choose either one.
Now, if a std chooses Comp. then marks in the maths column is 0, likewise for maths.
I am trying to print an individual report cards for 10 students. But one of the label for the optional should display Computer or Mathematics based on the value of the column. 
Here is the code i tried

```
'declare the variables
 Dim d As Database
 Dim r As Recordset
 Dim comp As Field, maths As Field

 'the data from the table 
 Set d = CurrentDb()
Set r = d.OpenRecordset("tbl_student")
Set id = r.Fields("Student ID")
Set comp = r.Fields("Computer")
Set maths = r.Fields("Mathematics")

'check for the column value
 While Not r.EOF
 If (comp = 0) Then
Me.labelOptional.Caption = "Mathematics"
ElseIf (maths = 0) Then
Me.labelOptional.Caption = "Computer"
    Else
    Me.labelOptional.Caption = "none"
   End If
```

The result is it captions all the labels the same for all students.

Comment: "I have 6 columns for 6 different subjects". Bad bad idea. You should store results per student per course. Do read up on normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display different values for different rows in report/form, you should use bound text boxes. Labels and unbound text boxes will be the same for all rows in details section. Add new calculated column for optional label in base query and use it instead of label.